# Python re.sub function

Tags: python

I need to convert a lot of view queries to BigQuery syntax.  My python script has been working great at replacing pieces of code with re.sub.  I need to remove a line containing "LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS"  What is wrong with this:

```
file_content = re.sub(r'LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS', '', file_content)
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? Did you try to read the documentation to make sure you understand how `re.sub` works?

Comment: file_content = re.sub(r'LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS', '', file_content)

Try to change the name of your variable, perhaps you can be getting the software a bit confused declaring a variable and calling it in the same line.

example:
    file = re.sub(r'LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS', '', file_content)

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing the whole line, you're just removing that part of the line.

```
file_contents = re.sub(r'.*LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS.*', '', file_content)
```

`.*` will match anything around the string up to, but not including, the newlines.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the ".*"  both in front of and behind the match string.  I was trying to be exacting.  The format of all of the files was wildly inconsistent.  I just have to settle for removing that exact string and replace it with a space to guarantee I would not inject an error.

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` will only remove the part of `file_content` that is matching with the regex. e.g.,

```py
>>> import re
>>> file_content = 'asdfas LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESSasdfasdf'
>>> file_content = re.sub(r'LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS', '', file_content)
>>> file_content
'asdfas asdfasdf'
```

OTOH,

```py
>>> file_content = 'asdfas LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESSasdfasdf'
>>> file_content = re.sub(r'.*LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS.*', '', file_content)
>>> file_content
''
```

This is because adding `.*` in the beginning will match everything from beginning of the line, similarly for `.*` at the end of the string.